# Не загружаются нужные типы файлов

Tags: yii2

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [ ['file'], 'file',
          'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif, docx, xlsx, pdf, djvu, rar, zip, 7z,txt',
          'maxSize' => Yii::$app->params['fileMaxSize'],
          //'skipOnEmpty' => false, // пропускать, если файл 0 размера
          'maxFiles' => 5,
          //'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 50MB'
        ],
        [ ['file'], 'required' ],
    ];
}
```

Не загружаются файлы с расширением: `rar, png`.
А загружаются, например, файлы с расширением: `txt, docx, pdf`, хотя вроде прописано правило `extensions`.

Где содержится ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел частичное решение проблемы, если посмотреть [сюда](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/tutorial-core-validators), а именно перейти к file и к 'checkExtensionByMimeType', и изменить значение по умолчанию на false, то получается решение проблемы, а именно теперь можно загружать файлы, формата rar. Почему именно этот формат не удается загружать без проверки соответствия майм тайпа непонятно.

В результате получено:

```
public function rules(){
    return [            
        ['file', 'file', 'extensions' => 'tar,png, jpg, jpeg, gif, docx, xlsx, pdf, rar, djvu, zip, 7z, txt,', 'maxSize' => Yii::$app->params['fileMaxSize'], 'maxFiles' => 5, 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false],
        [ ['file'], 'required' ],
    ];
}
```

А частичное потому, что приведение checkExtensionByMimeType в false не всегда может быть хорошо.